# What ship would complement a Rattlesnake in level 4 missions?

Tags: eve-online

I dual box in missions. Recently, due to a fit of sobriety, I lost my Abby and so now I need to replace it.

My main missioner flies a Rattlesnake with good drone skills, a complement of two types of sentries, one set of heavy drones, and one set of light drones. She has become so versatile I wonder how best a second character can support her. With my Abby I would blow up frigs as they cross within my 30k range. I was thinking either a Paladin or a Legion, but I am afraid that a Legion would require too much micromanagement to stay alive in level 4s.

Assuming a budget of 1.5-2 billion what would be a good (preferably Amarr) complement to my Rattlesnake for missions? (Don't say run incursions, I do that already with a Legion.)

Comment: Wouldn't a salvaging alt with a Noctis be more useful than a second combat ship?

Comment: I actually have that as well, I wait until the mission is mostly complete, then duck out with my Amarr pilot to get the Noctis. Just having the Noctis sitting around not doing much while one BS fights is kind of inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally put my second toon into a Noctis to salvage as I go.  A well tanked Rattlesnake should be able to hero tank almost any Level 4 mission, so easy mode involves popping all the triggers and grabbing all aggro with the Rattlesnake, setting Ogre IIs to aggressive, and then bringing in the Noctis to salvage wrecks as my drones pop the ships.

If, however, you are looking for combat on your second character with minimal management, why not fly another drone boat such as a Domi or a Gila?  Assign the drones from the second ship to your Rattlesnake pilot and control two flights of drones on your main combat character.

Lastly, if you're dead set on Amarr, the Paladin is the way to go.  Nothing will match the tank of a Rattlesnake, but the Paladin with T2 Tachyons will outclass almost any other mission ship's ability to apply large DPS.  If you're still looking for minimal combat management, a valid tactic would be to (once again) hero tank with the Rattlesnake, bring in the Paladin, and assign the Rattlesnake's drones to the Paladin.

Comment: Sweet thanks for the answer, quick follow up: T2 vs Faction Tachs. Thoughts?

Comment: I personally feel that the benefits of T2 ammo are enough to warrant the T2 guns.  But you don't want to spend the ISK on the T2 ammo (since T2 crystals to break eventually) and want to stick with T1 ammo, the faction guns might do better DPS with T1 ammo than the T2 guns.  Best bet would be to plug both options into EFT/EVEHQ/Pyfa and see what works best.  Unfortunately, I don't have any of those installed here at work.